# Power-time graphs for constant speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, power

i. What does the power-time graph for a car moving on a horizontal road at constant speed look like? Is it a horizontal line because the car engine is supplying a constant power, or is it zero because there is no change in kinetic energy or gravitational potential energy of the car (so no work is done and therefore power is zero)?

ii. If the same car now drives uphill at a constant speed and the slope of the hill is constant as well, what will the power-time graph look like? I think it will be a straight line going diagonally upwards because gravitational potential energy is increasing. Is that correct?

In both cases, all resistive forces are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $P = \frac{dW}{dt}$, where $W$ is the work. Then $P = F \cdot \frac{s}{dt} = F \cdot v$, where $v$ is velocity.

So, if the force acting on the body and the angle between the force and velocity vector does not change, then the power would definitely be constant. Here, we are considering power due to the engine. Therefore, force would be provided by the engine only.

So, in the first case, the engine must provide some force in order to counteract the frictional force, then the power must be constant, assuming pure rolling of tires. But if there are no frictional forces, the engine will not provide any power, as there is no force to counteract; hence in case (i), power will be $0$ (as $F = 0$, $F \cdot v = 0$).

In the second case, the component of gravity parallel to the road must be countered to go up, therefore force due to engine = force of gravity, hence assuming the slope doesn't vary, power shall be constant. ($F$ constant, $v$ constant, therefore $F \cdot v = $ constant).

Answer (score 1):

What you miss in your first point is that the car feels both aerodynamic and roling resistance. The engine has to supply power to counteract this resistance, otherwise the car will slow down and ultimately stop. The work that the engine does generally heats the air and the road.

Comment: I have edited the question. There are no resistive forces.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no resistive forces, so no friction and no external forces and the car moves in a straight line with no acceleration the engine is indeed not doing anything or at least not anything acting on the car. The supplied Power would be zero at any given time.

If you drive uphill and still move with constant velocity the car will have to create a force pointing in the direction of movement, acting against the constant gravitational pull. In that case a constant power would have to be provided.

Comment: Hi Zaph! Since the car is gaining height, its GPE is increasing, shouldn't power increase as well? Or are we saying that effect is countered because time is also increasing?

Comment: What does "GPE" mean? The Power needed for moving in straight line will be constant as long as the forces acting against the movement, that have to be compensated will be constant.

Comment: GPE stands for gravitational potential energy.

Comment: Yes its potential energy increasing at a constant rate is consistent with a constant power being supplied as power is energy supplied per unit of time. If no other force would act, a constant power supply would cause constant increase in kinetic energy instead.

Comment: $P = Driving force \times average speed$. So on a flat road, shouldn't the car have a constant power as well because we consider driving force not the resultant force?

Comment: If on a flat road with no frictional or other forces acting on the car, if there was any driving force applied to the car, it would not move with constant velocity but with accelerated one. So at constant velocity you would only have a power acting on the car, if there were any kind of resistive forces, which is obviously the physically real case and is what I assume fraxinus was referring to with his answer. Since you explicitly exclude resistive forces in your question and assume constant velocity, you implicitly set $Drivingforce = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, since the car is not gaining any potential energy, $\Delta PE = 0$. And since there is no change in the velocity of the car, $\Delta KE = 0$, too. Therefore, the work done is $0$. Thus,

\begin{align}
&\text{Power} = \frac{\text{Work}}{\text{Time}} \\
&\implies\text{Power} = \frac{0}{\text{Time}} \\
&\implies\text{Power} = 0 \\
\end{align}

Thus, power with respect to time would be represented by the positive x-axis.

---

In the second scenario, since the car moves with a constant velocity, $\Delta KE = 0$. But here, the car has a gain in potential energy, therefore $\Delta PE \neq 0$. Thus, work is being done.

But since the body is moving with a constant velocity, its vertical component will be constant, too. In other words, it rises by the same height per unit time. Thus, its $\Delta PE$ per unit time will be constant; constant work will be done per unit time.

Therefore, the power will be constant. Hence, power with respect to time would be represented by a horizontal line, parallel to the x-axis, with its y-intercept at a non-zero power level, having a rectangular area that represents power $\times$ time, i.e., work.

---

There is one more way to understand this.

\begin{align}
&\text{Power} = \frac{\text{Work}}{\text{Time}} \\
&\implies \text{Power} = \frac{\text{Force} \times \text{Displacement}}{\text{Time}} \\
&\implies \text{Power} = \text{Force} \times \frac{\text{Displacement}}{\text{Time}} \\
&\implies \text{Power} = \text{Force} \times \text{Average Velocity} \\
\end{align}

In the first scenario, since the velocity is constant, acceleration = $0$. Therefore, force = $\text{mass} \times \text{acceleration}$ = $0$, and so power = $0$.

In the second scenario, although the velocity is constant, the car is moving up, against gravity. Therefore, in the power formula, force = weight of the car. Moreover, as work is happening in increasing the gravitational potential energy, we will only consider the vertical component of the car's constant velocity.

\begin{align}
&\text{Power} = \text{Weight} \times \text{Average Vertical Velocity}
\end{align}

Therefore, power will be non-zero, and hence the graph.